# Object vs Class method programming on Rock Paper Scissors graphics applet?

Tags: java, oop, applet

I have to do a final project in programming designing a game of some sort and I decided on rock paper scissors. I started writing the program without any sort of object oriented programming style in mind, and realized I would have to change it to get maximum points for the project. However, when I rewrote it in OOP form, it would not work like the one created without OOP.

Here is my OOP program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RockPaperScissorss extends Applet
{
    protected String answer;
    protected Image rock, paper, scissors;
    protected boolean playAgain;
    public void init()
    {
        answer = Expo.enterStringGUI("What is your first draw?");
        rock = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Rock.gif");
        paper = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Paper.gif");
        scissors = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Scissors.gif");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Output output = new Output();
        playAgain = true;
        while(playAgain == true)
        {
        output.displayYouAndComp(g);
        output.getCompDraw();
        output.displayPic1(g);
        output.displayComp1(g);
        output.whoWon();
        output.printResult(g);
        output.playAgain();
        if(playAgain == true)
           init();
        }
    }
}

class Initialize extends RockPaperScissorss
{
    protected String again;  
    public void displayYouAndComp(Graphics g)
    {
        Expo.setFont(g,"Algerian",Font.BOLD,50);
        Expo.drawString(g,"You",0,50);
        Expo.drawString(g,"Computer",500,50);
    }

    public boolean playAgain()
    {
        again = Expo.enterStringGUI("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
        if(again.equals("Y") || again.equals("y"))
           playAgain = true;
        else
           playAgain = false;
        return playAgain;
    }
}

class Person extends Initialize
{       
    public void displayPic1(Graphics g)
    {
        if(answer.equals("rock"))
        g.drawImage(rock,0,100,this);
        else if(answer.equals("paper"))
        g.drawImage(paper,0,100,this);
        else 
        g.drawImage(scissors,0,100,this);
    }
}

class Computer extends Person
{    
    protected int draw;    
    public void getCompDraw()
    {
        draw = Expo.random(0,2);
    }

    public void displayComp1(Graphics g)
    {
        if(draw == 1)
        g.drawImage(rock,500,100,this);
        else if(draw == 2)
        g.drawImage(paper,500,100,this);
        else 
        g.drawImage(scissors,500,100,this);
    }
}

class Output extends Computer
{   
    protected boolean won;
    protected int tieGame;
    protected String result;
    protected String newArray[];    

    public String[] whoWon()
    {
        newArray = new String[1];
        String personAnswers[] = {answer};
        int compAnswers[] = {draw};
        for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
        {
           if(personAnswers[k].equals("rock"))
           {
              switch(compAnswers[k])
              {
                case 1: //rock
                     newArray[k] = "tie";
                     break;
                case 2: //paper
                     newArray[k] = "loss";
                     break;
                case 3: //scissors
                     newArray[k] = "win";
                     break;
              }
           }
           else if(personAnswers[k].equals("paper"))
           {
               switch(compAnswers[k])
               {
                   case 1:
                        newArray[k] = "win";
                        break;
                   case 2:
                        newArray[k] = "tie";
                        break;
                   case 3:
                        newArray[k] = "loss";
                        break;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               switch(compAnswers[k]) //equals scissors
               {
                   case 1: 
                        newArray[k] = "loss";
                        break;
                   case 2:
                        newArray[k] = "win";
                        break;
                   case 3:
                        newArray[k] = "tie";
                        break;
               }
           }
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public void printResult(Graphics g) 
    {
        String[] result = newArray;
        Expo.setFont(g,"Algerian",Font.BOLD,50);
        int x = 200;
        for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
        {
        if(result[k].equals("loss"))
           Expo.drawString(g,"You lost!",700,x);
        else if(result[k].equals("tie"))    
           Expo.drawString(g,"It's a tie!",700,x);
        else
           Expo.drawString(g,"You won!",700,x);
        }
    }
}
```

vs my non-OOP code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class RockPaperScissorsss extends Applet
    {
        String answer1, answer2, answer3; //first draw, etc.
        int firstDraw, secondDraw, thirdDraw;
        int tieGame;
        String[] newArray;
        Image rock, paper, scissors;
        boolean playAgain;
        String again;

        public void init()
        {
            answer1 = Expo.enterStringGUI("What is your first draw?");
            rock = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Rock.gif");
            paper = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Paper.gif");
            scissors = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Scissors.gif");
            newArray = new String[1];
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            playAgain = true;
            while(playAgain == true)
            {
            displayYouAndComp(g);
            getCompDraw();
            displayPic1(g);
            displayComp1(g);
            whoWon();
            printResult(g);
            playAgain();
            if(playAgain == true)
               init();
            }
        }

        public boolean playAgain()
        {
            again = Expo.enterStringGUI("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
            if(again.equals("Y") || again.equals("y"))
               playAgain = true;
            else
               playAgain = false;
            return playAgain;
        }

        public void displayYouAndComp(Graphics g)
        {
            Expo.setFont(g,"Algerian",Font.BOLD,50);
            Expo.drawString(g,"You",0,50);
            Expo.drawString(g,"Computer",500,50);
        }

        public void getCompDraw()
        {
            firstDraw = Expo.random(0,2);
            secondDraw = Expo.random(0,2);
            thirdDraw = Expo.random(0,2);
        }

        public void displayPic1(Graphics g)
        {
            if(answer1.equals("rock"))
            g.drawImage(rock,0,100,this);
            else if(answer1.equals("paper"))
            g.drawImage(paper,0,100,this);
            else 
            g.drawImage(scissors,0,100,this);
        }

        public void displayComp1(Graphics g)
        {
            if(firstDraw == 1)
            g.drawImage(rock,500,100,this);
            else if(firstDraw == 2)
            g.drawImage(paper,500,100,this);
            else 
            g.drawImage(scissors,500,100,this);
        }

        public String[] whoWon()
        {
            String personAnswers[] = {answer1};
            int compAnswers[] = {firstDraw};
            for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
               if(personAnswers[k].equals("rock"))
               {
                  switch(compAnswers[k])
                  {
                    case 1: //rock
                         newArray[k] = "tie";
                         break;
                    case 2: //paper
                         newArray[k] = "loss";
                         break;
                    case 3: //scissors
                         newArray[k] = "win";
                         break;
                  }
               }
               else if(personAnswers[k].equals("paper"))
               {
                   switch(compAnswers[k])
                   {
                       case 1:
                            newArray[k] = "win";
                            break;
                       case 2:
                            newArray[k] = "tie";
                            break;
                       case 3:
                            newArray[k] = "loss";
                            break;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   switch(compAnswers[k]) //equals scissors
                   {
                       case 1: 
                            newArray[k] = "loss";
                            break;
                       case 2:
                            newArray[k] = "win";
                            break;
                       case 3:
                            newArray[k] = "tie";
                            break;
                   }
               }
            }
            return newArray;
        }

        public void printResult(Graphics g) 
        {
            String[] result = newArray;
            Expo.setFont(g,"Algerian",Font.BOLD,50);
            int x = 200;        
            for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
            if(result[k].equals("loss"))
               Expo.drawString(g,"You lost!",700,x);
            else if(result[k].equals("tie"))    
               Expo.drawString(g,"It's a tie!",700,x);
            else
               Expo.drawString(g,"You won!",700,x);
            x += 200;
            }
        }
    }
```

I apologize in advance if the code is hard to understand. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it would not work like the one created without OOP" What doesn't work exactly? What is your new program doing that's wrong?

Comment: When I run the program, the only thing that shows up on the applet screen is the prompt "what is your first draw", "you", and "computer" while the non-OOP program executes everything written from the prompt to the display of rock, paper, or scissors, and the play again prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the reason is that since "Output" extends "RockPaperScissorss" that extends "Applet", when you execute "Output output = new Output();" in paint(), you're getting a different instance of an Applet that doesn't have access to "display"  You need to fix your inheritance.

However, I must add, your program fails to achieve OOP - you are only demonstrating one principles of OOP: Inheritance (extends).  You are missing the two other principles: Polymorphism (implements) and Encapsulation (sharing protected boolean playAgain across classes and other parts of your implementation violates this principal).  So, even if you get your code to work, I would fail you on your project unless you demonstrate all of the OOP principles.

Comment: I'm in a beginning Java course that did not go into great detail of OOP other than not putting all your code into the main class. Luckily, the assignment is not being graded for correct usage of OOP. Do you know how I can fix my code to get it to work?

Comment: The issues, I believe, is with this statement:  Output output = new Output();  It is instantiating a second Applet.  You should remove the inheritance of Initialize (make class Initialize extends RockPaperScissorss becomes class Initialize) and then pass-in the necessary objects or have other class return values you're program needs to operate.